# How can I prevent the user from selecting a date before today in the Joomla Calendar field?

Tags: date, joomla, calendar, field

I want to customize the calender field of Joomla inside the search module of the component adsmanger, basically I want to :

- Prevent the user from selecting a date before today.
- Prevent the user from typing in the field, he can only select a date using the calender.
- Set the current day as a default value

Here is the part of the generation of the calender field in component :

```
<?php
case 'date':

            $options = array();
            $options['size'] = 16;
            $options['maxlength'] = 16;
            if ($field->required == 1) {
                $options['class'] = 'adsmanager_required';
                $options['mosReq'] = '1';
                $options['mosLabel'] = "$strtitle";
            }
            else 
            {
                $options['class'] = 'adsmanager';
            }
            $return .= JHTML::_('behavior.calendar');
            if ($value != "") {
                if (function_exists("strptime")) {
                    $a = strptime($value, JText::_('ADSMANAGER_DATE_FORMAT_LC'));
                    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900);
                } else {
                    $timestamp = strtotime($value);
                }
                if ($timestamp != null)
                    $value = date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);
                else
                    $value = "";
            }
            $return .=  JHTML::_('calendar', $value, "$field->name", "$field->name", JText::_('ADSMANAGER_DATE_FORMAT_LC'), $options); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The calendar doesn't actually have a way to do exactly what you specified out of the box. There are some methods that will get you closer though.

The included method is to set the available years, which at least could keep them in this year.

```
Calendar.setRange(2013, 2020);
```

There is also a method in the javascript function to add an `onUpdate` handler which you could use to write your own comparison function to limit the date to today and forward. However, there doesn't seem to be a good way in Joomla to pass a function through to this position, since it should be part of the `Calendar.setup()` call. The code that generates the javascript is found at `libraries/joomla/html/html.php` at line 880ish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found that line but my website is about carpooling and I don't wanna let users choose a date in the past, what about disabling the possibility of typing the date in the field, and also about the default value ? thank you

Comment: Those are all possible options. I'm fairly confident that Joomla doesn't have a built in way to do what you want, so there is likely some significant coding ahead of you (if I had something lying around, I would post it). You may want to consider either trying a different calendar popup (You may want to look at the updated and commercial version of the calendar that ships with Joomla [here](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) ) or can look to try writing your own Javascript function to parse the results, either when the calendar is closed or on save.

Comment: Thank you again, I will give it a try, but you know I am not JS developer, I thought it can be fixed using PHP ...

Comment: You could potentially fix it with PHP, but it would not be as nice. You could also do a check after they submit the form to check if the date is valid (i.e. after today) and if not kick them back to the form page. (If using the standard model save function, `return false` should do most of this for you.) However, that can get frustrating for the user. Honestly, you should be doing that anyway in case the JS is disabled or fails...

Comment: You could write a custom rule which checks against now().  Then add the rule with AddPathRule.  It would not be hard at all to write that code.